# Matplotlib(python) - drawing stationary signal

Tags: python, math, numpy, formula

How can I draw plot of formula: x(t)=cos(2π·10t)+cos(2π·25t)+ cos(2π· 50t) +cos(2π·100t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple: Declare your t array, compute x(t) array, plot it with matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Declare t array
t = np.arange(0.0,2.0,0.01) # change your end point and step as you want it

# Compute x(t) with numpy
x = np.cos(2*np.pi*10*t) + np.cos(2*np.pi*25*t) + np.cos(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.cos(2*np.pi*100*t)

# Plot t with x
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I would suggest to stick to the [standard convention](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html#introduction) in the Numpy/Scipy community to always use `import numpy as np` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. This saves a lot of typing and will make it easier for other people to look at your code.